# "tax_query" parameter not working with WP_Query

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, tax-query

I have a custom post type called 'episode'. Attached to 'episode' I have a custom taxonomy called 'video_type' that contains two terms: "bonus-footage" and "episode"; "episode" contains two child terms "season-1" and "season-2" (other seasons will be added in the future). I want to grab only the most recent post of the 'episode' type but not include any posts from the 'bonus-footage' term. Below is the code I'm using for this:

```
<?php
$some_args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'video_type',
        'terms' => 'bonus-footage',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'include_children' => true,
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
     ),
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'episode',
);

$s = new WP_Query( $some_args );

if ( $s->have_posts() ) : $s->the_post();
    // Do something with this post.
endif;
?>
```

The query works as expected if a post in one of the 'season' terms is the newest, but if a post in "bonus-footage" is the newest, then it's loading that one. In other words my "tax_query" parameters appear to have no affect on the query. Am I not formatting the "tax_query" properly or am I missing something else?

I've also tried setting "tax_query" as below:

```
'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'video_type',
        'terms' => 'episode',
        'field' => 'slug',
    'include_children' => true,
        'operator' => 'IN'
),
```

but I'm still getting the same result.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The [`tax_query` parameter is an *array of arrays*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters), not just an array.

This:

```
'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'video_type',
        'terms' => 'episode',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'include_children' => true,
        'operator' => 'IN'
),
```

Should instead be this:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'video_type',
        'terms' => 'episode',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'include_children' => true,
        'operator' => 'IN'
    )
),
```

Comment: Thanks Chip. I'm curious as to the reason why Wordpress has it built this way?

Comment: So that multiple tax queries can be performed, using Booleans. See the linked Codex entry, under the "**Multiple Taxonomy Handling**" section.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me! Thanks man, I was banging my head off the wall on this one!

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to translate this into a url parameter and have it actually used by WP_Query. It just keeps getting ignored.

Comment: Thanks man!! this really helps me!

Comment: "Array of arrays" still creating problems in 2022. Haha. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's also worth to pay attention if you are formatting the rules correctly:

```
new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'vehicle',
    'tax_query' => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'brand',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'bmw',
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'brand',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'mercedes',
        ]
    ],
]);
```

This way you are fetching vehicles that have brand `bmw` OR `mercedes`.

If you want to fetch vehicles that have brand `bmw` AND `mercedes`:

```
new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'vehicle',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'brand',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => ['bmw', 'mercedes'],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to [@Lucas' answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/399123/226541), I noticed that I had to add the key:
'operator' => 'AND' under terms to perform the ANDing operation. Otherwise, it still ORs the query.